# Matching short month name to values in array with full month names

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting short month names, e.g Jan, Feb, Mar, in my data, which I need to convert to full month names, e.g January, February, March.

```
$content .= '<h3>'.$m[1].''; // gives me say 'Jan' for instance
```

I guess I would start by building an array of months -

```
$fullmonths = array("January","February",etc)
```

Then after that, what is the best way to compare $m[1] abbreviated month names to the fullmonths array and extract the full month name on match found. Thank you for any help'

Comment: array key=short name, value=long name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested the code, but should work in theory. Basically an array in PHP is a hashtable in implementation. So you can assign the short names as keys to it and values to be the full name of the month.

Now you can search for the key :

```
$fullMonthNames = array();
$fullMonthNames['Jan']='January';
$fullMonthNames['Feb']='February';
$fullMonthNames['Mar']='March';
echo 'Full name of this month is: '.$fullMonthNames[$m[1]]."\n";
```

Comment: Worked perfectly - Thank you!